# What is the cakePHP way of checking if a user is allowed to perform an action on a particular item?

Tags: cakephp

Working with cakePHP this is my situation:

I have Users and `Order`s. `Order`s are created by Users. Only the user that created the `Order` is allowed to edit it. (admins can also, but I don't think that is important).

I am using the standard Auth component and have an isAuthorized function in my OrdersController that checks if the user is logged in and stops users from performing actions that they are not allowed to perform.

I want to make a decision on whether or not the user can perform the action based on the params passed and the data that comes out of the database. i.e. does the user own the order they are trying to edit? I am currently checking inside each action if this is the case.

Is there a way that I can trigger the same workflow that is triggered by returning false from isAuthorized? maybe throwing an Exception?

I don't want to do these finer checks inside the isAuthorized function, because it will require ugly methods of accessing the passed params, and duplication of data retrieval. How does cakePHP expect me to handle this?

(I have more complicated checks to make in other controllers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you're looking for:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authorization-who-s-allowed-to-access-what

> overriding the AppController’s isAuthorized() call and internally
>   checking if the parent class is already authorizing the user. If he isn’t, then just allow him to access the add action, and conditionally access
>   edit and delete.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the link, that is exactly the situation I am in. I don't like a datasource access is needed before the action is called (because we are almost guaranteed to retrieve that data later in the action).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to get this to work. I have a simple example outlined here:
http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2009/04/22/simplistic-example-of-row-level-access-control-with-auth-security-and-app-model-in-cakephp/

It should give you an idea of how to handle this in general, and then you can build on top of that as one approach.

Comment: Thanks for the link, this is the sort of example I was after